# Programmatically open a specific tab of the Eclipse CDT project property page

Tags: eclipse, properties, eclipse-cdt

I would like to open a specific tab of the Eclipse CDT project property page from code. For example the screenshot below shows the property page open on the Build Steps tab.

[image: cdt project properties - build steps tab]

The following code opens the property page succesfully, but always the last accessed tab.

```
private void openProperties(IProject project) {
  String ID = "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.properties.Page_BuildSettings";
  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell shell = org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell();
  org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(
      shell, project,
      ID, null, null, 0)
      .open();
}
```

The thing I don't quite understand is the Settings page is declared using `extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages"` and has an ID. But the tabs are added using `extension point="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.cPropertyTab"` which does not include an ID. So how are the tabs addressed without an ID?

Comment: `PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn` just knows about property pages, it doesn't know anything about their contents.

Comment: Any idea how I can get a list of it's tabs from the property page?

Comment: You would have to look at the source of this specific property page as there is no standard way of doing this. I don't have CDT installed so I don't know how this page handles the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial solution, but hopefully it helps:

- Save the return value of `createPropertyDialogOn()`. It's a `PreferenceDialog`.
- Call `getSelectedPage()` on it to get the `IPreferencePage` representing the page.
- Most CDT preference pages, including the Build Settings page, extend from `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.newui.AbstractPage`. `AbstractPage` uses an SWT `TabFolder` widget to store the tabs.
- Here's the fuzzy part: get a hold of the `TabFolder` widget for the page. Unfortunately, it's not exposed via any public API, so I think your options are:

  - Use reflection. The `TabFolder` is stored as a protected field of the `AbstractPage` named `folder`.
  - Search the SWT widget hierarchy rooted at `page.getControl()`, where `page` is the `AbstractPage`, for a `TabFolder`.
- Once you have the tab control, you can use `getItemCount()` and `getItem(index)` on it to enumerate its items, which will be of type `TabItem`.
- On each `TabItem`, call `getData()` to retrieve the associated `ICPropertyTab`.
- Examine the `ICPropertyTab` object to see if it's the one you want to activate. In your case, that might be a check like `tab instanceof org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui.properties.BuildStepsTab`.
- Once you've found the right tab, activate it via `folder.setSelection(item)`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, will give your suggestion a try and report back.